# Decode Json data into PHP Variables

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, json, angularjs

Im sending my data to PHP file like this using angularJS ajax

`{ username: "someusername", password: "somepassword" }`

previously i used something like this to send data

```
var vars = "username="+fn+"&password="+ln;
```

but since angular sending data like JSON. i want to decode into PHP variables.

here my PHP code

```
if(isset($_POST['username']) && isset($_POST['password'])){
    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];
}

$sql = "SELECT * FROM member WHERE username = '$username' AND password = '$password'";
```

what i tried to do is something like this

```
$array = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'))
    $username = $array->username;
    $password = $array->password;


$sql = "SELECT * FROM member WHERE username = '$username' AND password = '$password'";
```

but not sure how to do it. also no idea about what happens in this section 
'file_get_contents('php://input')'
im sending data from local computer to internet server PHP file (Cross Domain)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To transform a PHP array into variables use the [extract function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.extract.php), however, this is not a good approach.

Decode the JSON into an array and use PHP's [filter functions](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.filter.php)

On the client side you need something like:

```js
$http.post(http://your.url,
  {"username"  : someUserName, "password": somePassword}
).then(function (data, status, headers, config) {
  // do things.
});
```

On the server side you should have:

```php
$input = json_decode( file_get_contents('php://input'), true );

$username = filter_var($array['username'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING));
$password = filter_var($array['password'], FILTER_UNSAFE_RAW));


// this should work but is bad practice. Don't do it.
// extract($input);
// $username and $password are now available to you
```

**Also, you need to improve you code to protect against SQL injection.**

You can read about it here: [how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) .

Comment: it worked with your previous edit. 
`$username = $array['username'];
$password = $array['password'];`

Comment: using this method is a better approach and also much more clear. I further improved my answer to include filters.

Answer (score -1):

Use $http.post in AngularJS, then pass in the JSON-data with a post, then just use the $_POST variable in PHP with json_decode, then you will have an associative array in PHP.

Comment: is there anyway to do it simply decode array into variables in PHP

Comment: Just use the index to reference it.. `$array['username'] = 'someusername'; $array['password'] = 'somepassword';`